# Need help installing wordcloud

Tags: python, windows, terminal, pip, word-cloud

Edited this post: I was incorrect about my commands in terminal, they work in powershell and thank you for the advice on the Windows subsytem for Linux.

QUESTION:
I am having trouble installing wordcloud and I'm not really understanding the errors I'm seeing (listed below). [Link to wordcloud github page](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud). I tried to pip install, conda install, and downloading the manual install using wget https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/archive/master.zip (the unzip command wasn't recognized in powershell). Help?

```
C:\Users\ghodg>pip install wordcloud
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pip
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be intending to use the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" but are actually using `cmd.exe` or PowerShell?

Comment: Should I be using powershell for all of these things instead?

Comment: It looks like you have two separate questions here that may or may not be related.

Comment: Yes, PowerShell is probably the way to go, but I think you would still need to install/activate Windows Subsystem for Linux if you want to use Linux-style commands.

Comment: I think you might be right. I didn't know about the subsytem for Linux. Let me try a few things with powershell and out the subsytem.

Comment: You might just need to open a terminal and type `bash` first.

Comment: Split the questions please :)

Comment: Updated cause I am stupid!

Answer (score 1):

The windows terminal does not have any of these commands. Those are Bash commands(command language). There is Git Bash which you can download from here: https://git-for-windows.github.io/ It has some commands missing, although it could help. And this too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about should be installed

EDIT: It may be the version of **pip**. Try `pip3 install wordcloud` If you have an error, you may try `sudo apt install python3-pip` **or** `(if you are a Windows user) py -m pip3 install wordcloud` **or** `py3 -m pip install wordcloud`. I am not sure which one will work, because I am a Linux user, although I had Windows before.

Comment: It does if you have [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) installed and activated.

Comment: and actually ls works in powershell too :) I just don't understand Microsoft why to not have just one "terminal" solution, but two - command prompt and power shell...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an [issue with setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/885/). You might need to upgrade setuptools and pip first with `pip install -U setuptools pip`.

Comment: I just tried that in terminal and powershell, I still get this same error:
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'  

The whole error message is pasted above

Comment: You might need to upgrade pip too in the same way.

Comment: Using this: pip install --upgrade pip ? I keep getting this error: AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'  (I keep trying to update/install setuptools and pip in both terminal and powershell....)

Comment: Hm... you might have to do a fresh install of `pip`, since it seems like its vendorized version of `pkg_resources` is borked.

Comment: No matter what I do I keep getting that attributeError, going to uninstall and reinstall python3. Do you think having anaconda or python2.7 installed is creating any kind or errors here?